# Why are the Chat users inconsistent?

Tags: bug, chat

This is the AU Meta user:

[image]

This is U&L user:

[image]

Why did the AU Meta post 189 days ago, but for U&L that is not applicable? I know that these are of course wrong - they both posted today. But could they be the same - both either "n/a" or "the begining of time" (that would work with the humorous descriptions for some like the [Stack Exchange bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2):

> I'm just a bot. Sometimes I post feed items, sometimes I post room status changes, sometimes I dream about electric unicorns.

Also, this one has posted today:

[image]

Sorry for the lack of freehand circles.